# Unable to load the plugin type - Update

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using a job with crm and I **update** a record of entity X the entity has one plugin - PostCreate message, no custom plugins about update. when I try to use  crm update  -  **service.Update(currEntity)** I get an error : **Unable to load the plugin type**, searching the web I found that I need to check if there is an update plugin that might cause a problem - I have none. What can cause that problem? what should I be looking for?

Comment: what is your trigger for your plugin which uses **service.Update(currEntity)**
On which entity is your trigger? Pre, Post, Create,update,delete and so on.

Need more info.

Comment: I would recommend to check your code, all the plugin steps might have a chance to trigger based on your business logic, also verify any OOB plugin steps interfering with yours like Activity feeds, etc. Do a process of elimination by commenting the code or disabling the steps related.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is vague, your net to catch it must be wide.  Start by disabling all of your plugins.  Did that resolve the issue?  If it didn't, you have something greater to deal with.  Assuming it did, enable the plug-ins 1 by 1 until you find the troubled plugin assembly and maybe step.  Did you reference a dll that doesn't exist on the server?  Did you forget to explicitly implement IPlugin?  Those types of things are what you should be looking for.